# Hide Path of Pages in jsf2 primefaces

Tags: jsf-2

My Developed Application is using primefaces , jsf2 , Spring

I have an issue with urls 
Urls in my application shows the path of each Page , 
Like 
/LTS/pages/secured/generalFeedback/fillFeedbackForm.xhtml

But I want it to be 
/LTS/fillFeedbackForm 
Without Path or Page extension 
Any Help ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [prettyfaces](http://ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/). It allows to define path, name, extension per each page.